# Why does typescript ignore modifications to locals in array callbacks?

Tags: typescript, callback

Specifically,

```
function foo(a: number[]) : number {
  let result = false;
  a.forEach((x) => {
    if (x === 5) {
      result = true;
    }
  });
  // Here ts reports:
  // "This condition will always return 'false' 
  // since the types 'false' and 'true' have no
  // overlap"
  if (result === true) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the above, tsc believes that result *cannot* take the value true, despite the assignment inside the callback. Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOA2gLoCUiOeRZiA3gLABQiiANsVIqWIBnEN34BeZBm5DiAbg5cMAOhSkAohggALNGgAetcQD4WirohjBEBxOPuIArLTacLXQSLF3EUUiHlzLgBfc2DqBTcrG09RCQc-AJcggT4QUiQARkiQ80EodKQABkjgoA)

I realize I could rewrite the above using eg `Array#some`, but in my real code I'm using `map` to produce a result, and this saves a second pass over the array just to set a flag.

Is there a way to make it recognize the fact that the callback may have been called?

Answer (score 1):

You are only modifing `result` in another blocked scope (the foreach callback).

TS has no way to know when this callback is going to be called. It will depend on the implementation of the function.

There is an [old open proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) to improve compiler understanding for immediatly-invoked methods.

Also, unless you're array is very big, always favor readability over premature optimisation, here `map` + `some`.

Comment: But ts does (or should) know that forEach calls the callback for each array element. And even for an arbitrary function, it *may* call the callback. So any side effects *may* happen. It doesn't need to know that the callback *is* called; just that it might be.

Comment: That's not what the maintainer of TS think. [Here is a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16928#issuecomment-312971683) about this from Anders Hejlsberg creator of TS.

Comment: Also there is a proposal to improve this, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Shame the issue is locked and not taking new comments, but I'll note here that the claim that 'Neither approach is more "safe" than the other, it's simply a matter of which cases get incorrectly identified' is obviously false. Assuming it's not called when it *might* can result in types being too narrow, which is always an error; assuming it might be called when it *can't* be can result in types that are too wide, which might be inconvenient, but isn't an error.